# How to get last inserted id in yii2 using createCommand?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I am using `yii2` php framework. I want insert record into database using `transaction`. How can I get last inserted id using `createCommand()`.

Please check following code,

```
$db = Yii::$app->db;
$sql = $db->createCommand()->insert('user', [
                             'name' => 'test',
                             'email_address' => 'test@test.com',
                             'phone_number' => '432432424',
                            ])->execute();
```

Comment: who ever marked it as duplicate needs to know that the duplicate answer mentioned is for **Yii1** and this question is for **Yii2**

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam And yet, the answers here seem to be the same as the answers on the duplicate.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel there is a difference in `Yii::$app->db` and `Yii::app()->db`, `Yii::$app` is for yii2 and `Yii::app()` is for Yii1 :)

Comment: Ok, I had read over that :). However, given the important detail is the same (calling `getLastInsertID()`), I don't think it warrants reopening.

Answer (score 43):

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->execute();
```

Then call function getLastInsertID,

```
 $id = Yii::$app->db->getLastInsertID();
```

Comment: Is this safe against race conditions? E.g. user A inserts into `items` and the id of this just inserted row is 5 and before A calls `getLastInsertID()` user B inserts another row. Now A calls said method. Will he get 5 or 6 ?

Comment: 6 Wins the race!

Answer (score 5):

You can do this using:

```
$lastInsertID = $db->getLastInsertID();
echo $lastInsertID;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect the last insert ID within a transaction in Yii using DAO?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24014286/how-to-detect-the-last-insert-id-within-a-transaction-in-yii-using-dao)